# SSMS Windows Opened with 'New Query'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, session, ssms, dbo

Do windows that were opened with 'New Query' on a Database object in SSMS remain targeted at that database, even after explicitly closing the connection through Object Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, windows that were opened with 'New Query' on a Database object in SSMS remain targeted at that database, even after explicitly closing the connection through Object Explorer.

Comment: In addition, there is a right click context menu that allows you to change this connection to a different database/server if you would like. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173761.aspx